# How to initialize an array using `repeating:count:` with distinct objects?

Tags: swift

Surprisingly, the code below prints `SAME` while the initializer should call the `Z()` constructor each time. How can I initialize the array using this method with distinct instances of `Z`?

```
import Foundation

class Z {
    var i: Int = 0
}

var z: [Z] = [Z](repeating: Z(), count: 10)

if z[0] === z[1] {
    print("SAME")
} else {
    print("NOT SAME")
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I made an extension just for this!

```
extension Array {    
    /// Create a new Array whose values are generated by the given closure.
    /// - Parameters:
    ///     - count:            The number of elements to generate
    ///     - elementGenerator: The closure that generates the elements.
    ///                         The index into which the element will be
    ///                         inserted is passed into the closure.
    public init(generating elementGenerator: (Int) -> Element, count: Int) {
        self = (0..<count).map(elementGenerator)
    }
}

class Z {
    var i: Int = 0
}

let z = Array(generating: { _ in Z() }, count: 10)

print(z)
```

Comment: self.indices returns zero.

Comment: Can you show me your test case?

Comment: I just fixed the typo (called it generating) with `init(generating elementGenerator): (Int) -> Element, count: Int)` and tried it with `let z = [Z](generating: { _ in Z() }, count: 10)`. Array is empty.

Comment: No luck. `self.indices` inside your `init` returns an empty range. I tested with Swift 3.1.

Comment: Oh yeah, i was playing around with it and forgot to refer that part. It's fixed now.

Comment: The use of the missing 'i' still needs fixing, but when changed to 'count' it does work. Thank you.